# Searching custom software download server (a gui like sourceforge would be nice)

Tags: download, software-distribution

We are searching for a software download server to deliver our software to our clients.
A sourceforge lookalike would be nice (menu with summary, files, support, wiki)

Is there any open source project or commercial software that provide this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Allura](http://sourceforge.net/projects/allura/), which is what SourceForge is built on.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/allura/